# Remove "null" from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have this code:

```
var returnValue = item.fname + " " + item.mname + " " + item.lname
returnValue.replace(null," ");
return returnValue ;
```

Sometimes one of the fields is null so `returnValue` is:

`"John null Doe"`

or

`"John something null"`

I want to get rid of the `"null"` but my code does not seem to work.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: `returnValue.replace('null'," ");`? Replace the `null` object, with null as a string

Comment: Instead of removing null afterwards, add a check to your fields and only add them if they are not null to avoid the issue alltogether. Otherwise, what would happen if someones name is 'Joe Nullmann'?

Comment: @Sirence He'll become 'Joe mann' and may finally get a value out of his name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
>    return (item.fname ? item.fname : '')  + " " + (item.mname ? item.mname : '') + " " + (item.lname ? item.lname : '');
```

Comment: This one did it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Rather than replacing null afterwards, only append the individual names if they are not null.

```
var returnValue = "";

if (item.fname !== null) {
    returnValue += item.fname + " ";
}

if (item.mname !== null) {
    returnValue += item.mname + " ";
}

if (item.lname !== null) {
    returnValue += item.lname;
}

return returnValue;
```

Alternatively, use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove nulls:

```
// store the names in an array
var names = [ item.fname, item.mname, item.lname ];

// filter the array to values where they are `!== null`
var notNullNames = names.filter(x => x !== null);

// join them with spaces
var returnValue = notNullNames.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var returnValue = (item.fname || " ") + " " + (item.mname || " ") + " " + (item.lname || " ");
return returnValue;
```

Be careful with mixing var types (string and null for example). Better make sure the variable is set or has a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you another technique: place your string parts to array, filter it and join it:

```
[item.fname, item.mname, item.lname].filter(v => !!v).join(' ')
```

Comment: you could filter with `Boolean` as cb.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's not recommended, as filter callback receives 3 arguments: currentElement, index, array while Boolean accepts just 1.

Comment: _"it's not recommended"_ - Why? `Boolean()` will just ignore the additional arguments

Comment: @Andreas that's the problem of JS and that's why big companies are using Flow and TypeScript. It's misuse of API. If it accepts a single param then you should pass only a single param

Comment: but you are using only one parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var returnValue = item.fname

if(item.mname)returnValue  += " " + item.mname

 if(item.lname)returnValue  += " " + item.lname

return returnValue
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Try ternary operator for null avoiding:

```
var returnValue = item.fname + " " + item.mname ? item.mname : "" + " " + item.lname
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most elegant solution is:

```
[item.fname, item.lname, item.lname].join(' ');
```

For example:

```js
const item = {}
item.fname = 'foo'
item.lname = 'bar'

console.log([item.fname, item.mname, item.lname].join(' '))
```

Otherwise you can use the or operator to skip falsy objects:

```js
const item = {}
item.fname = 'foo'
item.lname = 'bar'

const joined = (item.fname || '') + " " + (item.mname || '') + " " + (item.lname || '')

console.log(joined)
```